Trading Program Got Stuck Whether It Is Because of While Loop, or Something Else?
I'm backtesting an algorithm trading strategy running from 2023-01-01 to 2024-05-17, but the program got stuck after 2023-01-05 and it never moves on. Here's the output screenshot.
It stops after printing "df_002563 Loaded Successfully." and just stuck there and never moves on. Here's the entire output:
2023-01-03 09:30:00 - INFO  - df_002601 Loaded Successfully.

2023-01-03 09:30:00 - INFO  -      AVERAGE_PRICE  BEGIN_HOLD_NUM      ...        
SECURITY_CODE  SECURITY_NAME
0            20.43             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
1            20.30             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
2            20.57             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
3            20.42             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
4            20.83             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
5            21.20             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
6            21.67             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
7            21.10             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
8            22.12             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
9            21.80             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
10           21.86             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
11           21.98             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
12           22.01             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
13           22.17             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
14           22.45             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
15           22.38             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
16           22.52             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
17           22.60             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
18           22.79             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
19           22.53             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
20           22.35             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
21           22.51             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
22           21.53             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
23           21.52             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
24           21.55             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
25           21.61             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
26           21.72             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
27           21.77             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
28           21.84             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
29           21.77             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
..             ...             ...      ...                  ...            ...
152          46.39        680000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
153          32.05        800000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
154          33.30             NaN      ...               002601           龙佰集团
155          21.46             0.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
156          26.24          8000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
157          38.42         37200.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
158          25.25         16125.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
159          21.49      20163272.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
160          23.28         14900.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
161          22.66         17500.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
162          21.59        157142.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
163          20.99        630000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
164          20.79        670000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
165          20.04        752000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
166          17.99        197400.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
167          17.18         18000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
168          17.28         30000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
169          16.29         13000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
170          16.35             0.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
171          17.53        500000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
172          17.58        610400.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
173          17.51        670000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
174          22.16        600000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
175          20.75        798200.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
176          21.58        852000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
177          26.31        670000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
178          26.87        872000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
179          26.69        650000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
180          19.34        470000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团
181          22.72        620000.0      ...               002601           龙佰集团

[182 rows x 19 columns]

2023-01-03 09:30:00 - INFO  - 2023-01-03 today's to_buy List: 

2023-01-03 09:30:00 - INFO  - []

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  - df_601028 Loaded Successfully.

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  -     AVERAGE_PRICE  BEGIN_HOLD_NUM      ...        
SECURITY_CODE  SECURITY_NAME
0          10.410           47900      ...               601028           玉龙股份
1          12.398           47900      ...               601028           玉龙股份
2          12.391            8400      ...               601028           玉龙股份
3          12.403           27700      ...               601028           玉龙股份
4          12.540           15000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
5          12.600           32200      ...               601028           玉龙股份
6          12.535           16300      ...               601028           玉龙股份
7          12.640           26400      ...               601028           玉龙股份
8          12.511           33000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
9          12.950           10000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
10         12.940               0      ...               601028           玉龙股份
11         12.935            9800      ...               601028           玉龙股份
12         12.901           41000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
13         12.920           23000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
14         12.747               0      ...               601028           玉龙股份
15         12.750           36000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
16         12.773            8000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
17         12.808               0      ...               601028           玉龙股份
18         12.730           18100      ...               601028           玉龙股份
19         12.780           16400      ...               601028           玉龙股份
20         12.750           26000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
21         12.958           10000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
22         12.870           45000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
23         12.960            8000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
24         13.180           35000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
25         13.100            5000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
26         13.070               0      ...               601028           玉龙股份
27         13.473           20000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
28         13.500               0      ...               601028           玉龙股份
29         13.890           83000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
..            ...             ...      ...                  ...            ...
60         25.000        35000000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
61         27.200          760000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
62         21.070        37500000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
63         21.990        37800953      ...               601028           玉龙股份
64         22.197        38700000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
65         23.700        43000000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
66         23.130        41700000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
67         23.320          770000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
68         23.600          415000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
69         21.600          840000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
70         17.000        43000000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
71         17.740          880000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
72         17.330          910000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
73         17.160          945000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
74         16.820         2000000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
75         16.875         1000000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
76         17.400          309000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
77         17.200          339000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
78         16.800           50000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
79         15.780           27500      ...               601028           玉龙股份
80         16.100          364000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
81         15.890           30000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
82         16.000          425000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
83         15.580          500000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
84         14.758           78000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
85         15.480           66000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
86         15.150           68000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
87         11.430           78500      ...               601028           玉龙股份
88         11.126           80000      ...               601028           玉龙股份
89         10.880          100000      ...               601028           玉龙股份

[90 rows x 19 columns]

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  - df_603909 Loaded Successfully.

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  -     AVERAGE_PRICE  BEGIN_HOLD_NUM      ...        
SECURITY_CODE  SECURITY_NAME
0          15.350            1500      ...               603909           建发合诚
1          15.514         1368280      ...               603909           建发合诚
2          15.160         1348280      ...               603909           建发合诚
3          15.247        16087500      ...               603909           建发合诚
4          14.847        16043200      ...               603909           建发合诚
5          14.500         4416030      ...               603909           建发合诚
6          11.650         4386030      ...               603909           建发合诚
7          11.588        15960000      ...               603909           建发合诚
8          11.405         4344630      ...               603909           建发合诚
9          11.360        15922800      ...               603909           建发合诚
10         11.189        15858800      ...               603909           建发合诚
11         11.020        15813800      ...               603909           建发合诚
12         10.948        15800100      ...               603909           建发合诚
13         10.877         1330280      ...               603909           建发合诚
14         10.799         1289180      ...               603909           建发合诚
15         10.810         1272880      ...               603909           建发合诚
16         10.800         4314630      ...               603909           建发合诚
17         10.828        15720100      ...               603909           建发合诚
18         10.860        15710100      ...               603909           建发合诚
19         10.940         4294630      ...               603909           建发合诚
20         10.977        15655500      ...               603909           建发合诚
21         10.806         1269380      ...               603909           建发合诚
22         10.480         1269380      ...               603909           建发合诚
23         10.500         1268380      ...               603909           建发合诚
24         10.400         4274630      ...               603909           建发合诚
25         10.540         1267880      ...               603909           建发合诚
26         10.560         4254630      ...               603909           建发合诚
27         10.592         4249630      ...               603909           建发合诚
28         10.620               0      ...               603909           建发合诚
29         10.610         4244630      ...               603909           建发合诚
30         18.000          601225      ...               603909           建发合诚
31         15.620         4520940      ...               603909           建发合诚
32         15.520         4550940      ...               603909           建发合诚
33         15.620         4650940      ...               603909           建发合诚
34         15.470         4692500      ...               603909           建发合诚
35         15.550         4702500      ...               603909           建发合诚
36         15.500         4812500      ...               603909           建发合诚
37         14.450         4476400      ...               603909           建发合诚
38         14.030         4981900      ...               603909           建发合诚
39         13.860         5513200      ...               603909           建发合诚
40         19.580          837317      ...               603909           建发合诚
41         19.630          900000      ...               603909           建发合诚
42         20.050         3457500      ...               603909           建发合诚
43         20.030         3487500      ...               603909           建发合诚
44         18.750         3938064      ...               603909           建发合诚
45         16.180         4262500      ...               603909           建发合诚
46         17.360         4280100      ...               603909           建发合诚
47         17.310         4411900      ...               603909           建发合诚
48         17.020         4934300      ...               603909           建发合诚
49         16.990         4987200      ...               603909           建发合诚
50         16.740         5105500      ...               603909           建发合诚
51         17.070         5183200      ...               603909           建发合诚
52         16.980         5250000      ...               603909           建发合诚

[53 rows x 19 columns]

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  - 2023-01-04 today's to_buy List: 

2023-01-04 09:30:00 - INFO  - []

2023-01-05 09:30:00 - INFO  - df_002563 Loaded Successfully.

Here's my thought process: initially I'm thinking maybe I'm running into an infinite loop, since my code has a while-loop. And yet I haven't been able to find anything logically wrong with my while-loop. Here's part I (for stock) of the while-loop:
# Acquire the status of stock orders
while True:
    # If all stock orders are held: 
    if Stock_Order.status == 'held':
        print("Stock " + str(stock) + "orders are all held! transaction price: " + str(Stock_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Stock_Order.filled))
        # Hedge the dominant contract of HS300 Index Futures with the same value
        # Set the margin rate of index futures to be 15%
        margin_rate = 0.15
        set_option('futures_margin_rate.IF', margin_rate)
        future = get_dominant_future('IF')
    
        amount_f = int(amount_s * current_data[stock].day_open * margin_rate / current_data[future].day_open)
        # pindex = 1 represents that placing orders within sub-account subportfolio[1]
        # Return an Order object
        Future_Order = order(future, - amount_f, style = LimitOrderStyle(current_data[future].day_open), side = 'short', pindex = 1)
        break
        
    # Else if no stock orders are held: 
    elif Stock_Order.status == 'open':
        print("Stock " + str(stock) + "no orders are held!")
    # Else if part of stock orders are held: 
    elif Stock_Order.status == 'filled':
        print("Stock " + str(stock) + "orders are partially held! Transaction price: " + str(Stock_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Stock_Order.filled))
    # Else if stock orders are canceled (maybe partially held)
    elif Stock_Order.status == 'canceled':
        print("Stock " + str(stock) + "orders are canceled! Transaction price: " + str(Stock_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Stock_Order.filled))
        break
    # Else if stock orders are rejected by the Exchange (maybe partially held)
    elif Stock_Order.status == 'rejected':
        print("Stock " + str(stock) + "orders are rejected by the Exchange! Transaction price: " + str(Stock_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Stock_Order.filled))
        break

The idea is to loop through the stock orders until all orders are complete, and then place the future orders. Here's Part II of while-loop, for the future orders:
# Acquire the status of future orders    
while Stock_Order.status == 'held':
    # If all future orders are held:
    if Future_Order.status == 'held':
        print("Future " + str(future) + "orders are all held! transaction price: " + str(Future_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Future_Order.filled))
        break
            
    # Else if no future orders are held:
    elif Future_Order.status == 'open':
        print("Future " + str(future) + "no orders are held!")
    # Else if part of future orders are held:
    elif Future_Order.status == 'filled':
        print("Future " + str(future) + "orders are partially held! Transaction price: " + str(Future_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Future_Order.filled))
    # Else if future orders are canceled (maybe partially held)
    elif Future_Order.status == 'canceled':
        print("Future " + str(future) + "orders are canceled! Transaction price: " + str(Future_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Future_Order.filled))
        break
    # Else if future orders are rejected by the Exchange (maybe partially held)
    elif Future_Order.status == 'rejected':
        print("Future " + str(future) + "orders are rejected by the Exchange! Transaction price: " + str(Future_Order.price) + "; transaction amount: " + str(Future_Order.filled))
        break

Not being able to find a logical bug in the previous 2 while loops, I began to look at where the program stops. Before 2023-01-05, after it prints "df_XXXXXX Loaded Successfully." it always prints out the actual DataFrame: df_XXXXXX. But after printing "df_002563 Loaded Successfully.", the program fails to print out the actual DataFrame of df_002563. Here's what I tried with my code for this part:
# If df_today_change is not an empty dataframe, for {code} values in 'SECURITY_CODE' column, read the corresponding {code}.xlsx file
# and store it into a dataframe named df_{code}.
if not df_today_change.empty:
    for code in list(df_today_change['SECURITY_CODE']):
        try:
            file_name = f"{code}.xlsx"
            df_variable_name = f"df_{code}"
            df_code = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(read_file(file_name)), converters = {'SECURITY_CODE': str})
            globals()[df_variable_name] = df_code
            print(f"{df_variable_name} Loaded Successfully.")
            print(globals()[df_variable_name])
            df_code['CHANGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_code['CHANGE_DATE']).dt.date
            
            # For every df_{code}, if values of 'CHANGE_DATE' column, i.e. date, differs from current_date in no more than 30 days, 
            # calculate the corresponding values of 'CHANGE_AMOUNT'/market capital of {code} to get the total net ratio of shareholding
            # increase. If it is >= threshold, then put the stock {code} into to_buy list.
            total_ratio_code = 0.0
            for i in list(df_code.index):
                change_date = df_code['CHANGE_DATE'][i]
                if (current_date - change_date).days <= 30 and (current_date - change_date).days >= 0:
                    # Calculate the net ratio of shareholding increase.
                    df_valuation_code = get_valuation(normalize_code(code), start_date = change_date, end_date = change_date, fields = 'market_cap', count = None)
                    market_cap_code = df_valuation_code['market_cap'][0] * 100000000
                    total_ratio_code += df_code['CHANGE_AMOUNT'][i] / market_cap_code * 100

            if total_ratio_code >= threshold and normalize_code(code) not in to_buy:
                to_buy.append(normalize_code(code))
                print("Stock: " + code + "accumulated net shareholding increase within 30 days is " + str(total_ratio_code) + "%, >= " + str(threshold) + "%, put into to_buy list: ")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"File {file_name} Not Found.")
            
    print(str(current_date) + " today's to_buy List: ", to_buy)
else:
    print("df_today_change is Empty. Today there are no executive or core technology employees increase their stock shareholds.")

Please pay attention that after "globals()[df_variable_name] = df_code", it has "print(f"{df_variable_name} Loaded Successfully.")" and right after that, it prints out the entire dataframe with code "print(globals()[df_variable_name])". Here's this part of code:
df_code = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(read_file(file_name)), converters = {'SECURITY_CODE': str})
globals()[df_variable_name] = df_code
print(f"{df_variable_name} Loaded Successfully.")
print(globals()[df_variable_name])

In fact df_002563 is just a regular dataframe. Here's what it looks like in its original excel table:

Can anyone help me with it please? I don't understand why my program stops after printing out "df_002563 Loaded Successfully." without printing out the dataframe of df_002563. It got stuck there forever, which seems that there are logical errors within my while-loop. I can't figure out where the bug belongs. Thanks!

Is it possible that something is wrong with the excel sheet? Your loops will hang if there isn't a set stock status. Try putting an else after the check for a rejected status that throws an error and see if you get anything.

Excel file get from here or other?

@BenchVue I got it from here: with open('target_list_onlynumber.txt', 'r') as file:
target_list_onlynumber = file.read()
df = pd.DataFrame(
requests.get('https://datacenter-web.eastmoney.com/api/data/v1/get?reportName=RPT_EXECUTIVE_HOLD_DETAILS&columns=ALL&filter=(SECURITY_CODE%3D"603659")')
.json().get('result').get('data'))
df.to_excel('G:/ExecutiveHoldings/603659.xlsx', index = True)

@BenchVue I type in each stock code (for example 603659) by my self. I could have used a for-loop, but the website (www.eastmoney.com) uses anti-scraping, so I have to type in each stock code once every time.

603659 is one example, how to get all of SECURITY_CODE list?

@BenchVue Thanks for your question. To get all securities,             all_stocks = list(get_all_securities(types = ['stock'], date = None).index)                 , where "get_all_securites" is an JoinQuant.com API. Here's a link to that API https://www.joinquant.com/help/api/help#api:数据获取函数. My apologize that it only has Chinese-language version.

I think I can get all stock code list, what is final goal from 2023-01-01 to 2024-05-17 for all stock?

@BenchVue filter out stocks whose senior executives' net increase in their shareholdings >= 0.2% within 30 days. Buy those stocks while hedging HS300 Index Futures. Backtest the strategy from 2023-01-01 to 2024-05-17 (since the data I collect is from 2004-XX-XX to 2024-05-17) to see how this trading strategy performs.

I try it based on your commend. I hope to address your final goal.

Based on your comment, I made demo Python program to calculate 2% increase by summation of the change ratio within the same stock code(SECURITY) and the last 30 days. To add two new columns, one for "SUM_RATIO" and "Recommend" Buy or not.
Overview

Input Data is the last my answer's excel file in here
Demo.py
import pandas as pd

def load_data_from_excel(file_name):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
        print(f'Data successfully loaded from {file_name}')
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error loading data from {file_name}:', e)
        return None
    
def save_filtered_data(df, start_date, end_date, output_file):
    filtered_df = df[(df['CHANGE_DATE'] >= start_date) & (df['CHANGE_DATE'] <= end_date)]
    filtered_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
    print(f'Data successfully saved to {output_file}')

# Step 1
df = load_data_from_excel("./all_by_date.xlsx")
if df is not None:
    # Step 2, Save filtered data
    save_filtered_data(df, '2023-01-01', '2024-05-17', './partial_by_date.xlsx')
else:
    print('No data loaded.')


# Step 3: Read the data from "partial_by_date.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel('./partial_by_date.xlsx')

# Step 4: Sort the DataFrame by "SECURITY_CODE" (ascending), "CHANGE_DATE" (descending), and "CHANGE_SHARES" (descending)
df['CHANGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CHANGE_DATE'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['SECURITY_CODE', 'CHANGE_DATE', 'CHANGE_SHARES'], ascending=[True, False, False])

# Step 5: Save the sorted DataFrame to "sort-by-code.xlsx"
sorted_df.to_excel('./sort-by-code.xlsx', index=False)

# Step 6: Read the data from "sort-by-code.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel('./sort-by-code.xlsx')

# Ensure CHANGE_DATE is in datetime format
df['CHANGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CHANGE_DATE'])

# Step 7: Initialize new columns "SUM_RATIO" and "RECOMMEND" with default values
df['SUM_RATIO'] = 0.0
df['RECOMMEND'] = ''

# Sort by SECURITY_CODE and CHANGE_DATE descending
df = df.sort_values(by=['SECURITY_CODE', 'CHANGE_DATE'], ascending=[True, False])

# Iterate over each SECURITY_CODE
for security_code in df['SECURITY_CODE'].unique():
    security_code_df = df[df['SECURITY_CODE'] == security_code]
    
    # Iterate over each row within the group
    for i in range(len(security_code_df)):
        current_row = security_code_df.iloc[i]

        # Calculate the sum of CHANGE_RATIO from the current row to the end for the same SECURITY_CODE
        change_ratio_sum = security_code_df.iloc[i:]['CHANGE_RATIO'].apply(
            lambda x: x if current_row['CHANGE_SHARES'] >= 0 else -x
        ).sum()
        
        # Assign the calculated sum to the "SUM_RATIO" column for the current row
        df.loc[current_row.name, 'SUM_RATIO'] = change_ratio_sum
        
        # Step 8: Set the "RECOMMEND" flag if the sum is >= 0.02
        if change_ratio_sum >= 0.02:
            df.loc[current_row.name, 'RECOMMEND'] = 'Buy'

# Step 9 Save the updated DataFrame to a new Excel file
df.to_excel('./recommend.xlsx', index=False)
print('Data successfully saved to recommend.xlsx')

Logic
SUM_RATIO

to calculate the SUM_RATIO for each row, which is the sum of the CHANGE_RATIO values for all rows from the current row to the last row for the same SECURITY_CODE. Additionally, if the CHANGE_SHARES value is negative, the CHANGE_RATIO should be considered negative in the summation.

Example
Example:
Assume we have the following sorted data for SECURITY_CODE = 35:



SECURITY_CODE
CHANGE_DATE
CHANGE_SHARES
CHANGE_RATIO
SUM_RATIO
RECOMMEND




35
2024-03-04 00:00:00
363800
0.0144
0.1824
Buy


35
2024-02-28 00:00:00
22000
0.0009
0.1690
Buy


35
2024-02-28 00:00:00
3000
0.0001
0.1681
Buy


35
2024-02-26 00:00:00
5000
0.0002
0.1680
Buy


35
2024-02-23 00:00:00
149500
0.0059
0.1678
Buy


35
2024-02-21 00:00:00
98700
0.0012
0.0018



35
2024-02-20 00:00:00
50100
0.0006
0.0006



42
2023-05-12 00:00:00
-19600
0.0029
-0.0029




For the first row (2024-03-04), SUM_RATIO is calculated as:
SUM_RATIO = SUM(0.0144, 0.0009, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0059, ..., 0.0006) = 0.1824
Since 0.1824 >= 0.02, RECOMMEND is set to "Buy".
But 2024-02-21's SUM_RATIO is 0.0018 not recommended to buy.
And the calculation group only within same SECURITY CODE.
The RECOMMEND column

is used to provide a recommendation based on the calculated SUM_RATIO for each row in the dataset

If the calculated SUM_RATIO is greater than or equal to 0.02 (i.e., a net increase of 2% or more), set the RECOMMEND value to "Buy".
Result

